# How to call function before and after all request using express

Tags: node.js, express

I have rest api in node using express.

I have some endpoits...

```
router.get('/admin/logs', (req, res) => {
```

I want call specific function when ALL endpoints called.

How can I do this?

So, easy way is put function call to every requests get.

But is there any global way?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need to use any third party NPM at all. You can create a middleware that will be executed after each API call.**
Note: You can also get your previous req object back as well here so you can access something like this -> req.user.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.on('finish', async () => {
// You might have to add a logic here like if(req.user) then perform following things
// Do whatever you want to do here after every API call finishes
// you can access res.statusCode, req.method etc.
});
next();
});
```

Comment: Just a warning that this can cause a [memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78240397/is-my-closure-in-an-expressjs-middlware-causing-a-memory-leak) if your callback creates a closure

Answer (score 4):

You can put a handler before all other calls using [Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html), but sadly not after. As an example:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    log.info("Hello!");
    next();
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.end("That should work");
});
```

If you wanted to put a call *after* all requests, you could replace the `.end` function on `res`, putting your own function there which does some custom handling and calls the real `.end()`, but I wouldn't recommend this (monkeypatching is bad!).

Answer (score 1):

put a middleware  at the start of your script and use this [on-finished](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-finished)

```js
var onFinished = require('on-finished')


router.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('new request')
    
    onFinished(res, function (err) {
      console.log('request end')
    })
    
    next()

});
```